# Can we use Asp.net Identity API in windows/desktop applications as well?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, password-hash

I have a project which has a **asp.net mvc based portal** which manages user authentication/authorization using Asp.net Identity API.

The project also consists of a **windows service/EXE** which would poll an MSMSQ queue to get new users information and would save them into the Asp.net Identity Database(used by web project mentioned above).

so my question is - "**Can we use Asp.net Identity API in desktop applications too?**". The requirement only arises, because user's password hash has to be created, and I am using the default one which is provided by .net framework. So if I am creating a new user into the Asp.net Identity database, then I would need to create the password hash there too.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 5):

Identity does not take dependency directly on MVC, but it relies on OWIN to set the cookie and authentication. But if you need to check user password against stored hash, manipulate user records, etc. Why not?

You might experience a big pile of dependent packages (ASP.Net) added to your desktop project, but if you don't mind this - there is a possibility you can make it work.

On the other hand, there is [Identity Server](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3) which can work with MVC project and with Desktop project - without having to add Identity directly into your desktop application - also have a look into that.